# Typescript: Return Generic as string

Tags: typescript

How i can return generic type as string in this function?

```
const actionName = <P extends string>(path: P) => <A extends string>(action: A): string => `${path}/${action}`;

const path = actionName('filter');
const action = actionName('OPEN');
```

expected type in `action` is are `'filter/OPEN'`, but i get just `'OPEN'`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string for literal types.

Here is an example of how to use it with generic type for your case

```js
const actionName = <P extends "filter" | "Sort">(path: P) => <
  A extends "OPEN" | "CLOSE"
>(
  action: A,
) => `${path}/${action}` as `${P}/${A}`;

const path = actionName("filter")("OPEN");
```

Comment: Amazing! I modificated you solution, it's perfect fit! Thank you! 

const actionName = <P extends string>(path: P) => <A extends string>(action: A): `${P}/${A}` =>
  `${path}/${action}` as `${P}/${A}`;

Comment: @FLWRZ4U don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Ok, you shouldn't extend with string, that does not work, you should extend with exact values

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the correct usage of the generic function. The function `actionName` is creating a function within a function so in order to get the desired data you need a nested call to it to reach all the levels of it. So the first level is covered by `path` where it sets the path as 'filter' and then `action` completes the second level by providing the action as 'OPEN' to `path`. Try this

```
const actionName = <P extends string>(path: P) => <A extends string>(action: A): string => `${path}/${action}`;

const path = actionName('filter');
const action = path('OPEN');

console.log(typeof action, action);
//string filter/OPEN
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution doesn't fit because function return simple string type

Comment: I want the function to return a literal string

Comment: Yeah that's the way actionName is defined to return the string as 'filter/OPEN'

Comment: I still get are "string" type, not string literal :(

Comment: What do you want the action to return?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Okey, i'll try again, thank you!

Comment: I understood what you wanted to convey, but this is not what I need. The function is working correctly, I need the correct TYPE of the variable to be written to the variable

Comment: I want get this result
console.log(typeof action, action);
//filter/OPEN filter/OPEN

Comment: I see.. okay let me check

Comment: How i can resolve this problem? Please, help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved!

```
const actionName = <P extends string>(path: P) => <A extends string>(action: A): `${P}/${A}` => `${path}/${action}` as `${P}/${A}`;
```